# Convert matrix to factor

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am trying to apply table function but I got this error, so I think that because the test is a factor and the prediction is a matrix:

> Error in table(rfe_nB_test_folds[, 7], rfe_nB_predict) :
>       all arguments must have the same length

for that, I need to convert prediction result to factor so I can use it on table function, but I get this error and I think that because of 10 cross-validation because when I try it without 10 cross-validation it works:

> Error in `[.default`(rfe_nB_predict, , 2) :
>     incorrect number of dimensions

My code:

```
set.seed(100)
rfe_nB_folds<-createFolds(BC_bind$outcome, k=10) #create folds 
rfe_nB_fun <- lapply (rfe_nB_folds, function(x){
  rfe_nB_traing_folds<-BC_bind[-x,]
  rfe_nB_test_folds<-BC_bind[x,]
  #build the model 
  rfe_nB_model<-naiveBayes(outcome ~ ., data = rfe_nB_traing_folds)  #test the  model
  rfe_nB_predict<-predict(rfe_nB_model,rfe_nB_test_folds[-7],type="raw")
  rfe_nB_predict<-as.factor(rfe_nB_predict)
  CR<-roc.curve(rfe_nB_test_folds[,7], rfe_nB_predict[,2])
  print(CR)
  rfe_nB_table<-table(rfe_nB_test_folds[,7],rfe_nB_predict)
  rfe_nB_confusionMatrix<-confusionMatrix(rfe_nB_table,positive = "R") #to see the matrex of echo flods
  return (rfe_nB_confusionMatrix$table)
  })
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm added my code to the question, and here is the class and length
`> class(rfe_nB_test_folds[,7])
[1] "factor"
> length(rfe_nB_test_folds[,7])
[1] 20
> class(rfe_nB_predict)
[1] "matrix"
> length(rfe_nB_predict)
[1] 40`

Comment: Please reread the link! If I run your code I will immediately get an error as `BC_bind` is not defined, so your example isn't complete, and I doubt if it is verifiable.

Comment: the BC_bind is the dataset, I uploaded it here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsz07fkme5nlz4s/WPDC.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I'm used specific columns so I saved them on BC_bind as shown in the code.

```
Top_6featurs <- wpdc[,c(33,11,10,32,29,12)] #column number of top 6 featur
BC_bind <- data.frame(cbind(Top_6featurs , wpdc$outcome))
```